# Changing the application title of an MFC app on the windows 7/8 jump list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, taskbar, jump-list

Which setting in an MFC app controls the title shown in the windows 7/8 jump-list, just below the actual list of jumps, above the pin application option?

[image: Example]

This is mainly so that a localised string can be used for non-english systems.

My first thought on this problem was that it could be set in the version resource file, although adding a new localised section (sweden in this case) and setting the description/file name does not seem to affect the text i'm interested in.

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg281362.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36561/Windows-Goodies-in-C-Jump-Lists.

Comment: @MariusBancila Great links, a bit of clicking around through them sent me to the right place, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured this one out, the name used here and in several other places is set in a registry key for the application at

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\AppName.exe]
"FriendlyAppName"="This text is shown"
```

Some documentation can be seen here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#applications